I want to convert my Aura component to lwc
html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
     <lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI" />
    <div>
        <lightning:button label="Select CX Coordinator Name" onclick="{!c.selectRoleAction}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>

JS
({
    selectRoleAction : function( cmp, event, helper) {
        var actionAPI = cmp.find("quickActionAPI");
        var args = {actionName: "ClientSatisfactionPlan__c.SelectResponsibleRoles"};
        actionAPI.selectAction(args);
    },

})


Your aura component uses the quickActionAPI to run the quick action. In the LWC you need to use the navigationmaxin to run the quick action on the click of a button.
LWC Code::
HTML::
<template>
        <lightning-button label="Select CX Coordinator Name" onclick={selectRoleAction}></lightning-button>
</template>

JS::
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class SelectCxCoordinatorName extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

        selectRoleAction() {
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                        type: "standard__objectPage",
                        attributes: {
                                objectApiName: "ClientSatisfactionPlan__c",
                                actionName: "SelectResponsibleRoles",
                        },
                });
        }
}

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-navigate-quick-action.html
